# Create Sql Server view using table name from sysobjects table

Tags: sql, sql-server, view, sql-server-2012

I have around 200 tables. I want to create a `view` from all these tables. I feel it is inefficient to hardcode all the table names and do an `UNION ALL` in the view definition.

Instead I am planning to retrieve the table name from `sysobjects` table like

```
 Select name from sysobjects where name like 'Warehouse_Inventory%'
```

How can I use these table names and create a `view` out of it?

Note: I am selecting only 10 columns which are common. If any column is not present in a table, I want to display NULL for it.

Comment: Unless all the columns in these tables are same it is going to be hard to do a union for these tables. You need dynamic SQL for this. If it's a JOIN rather than UNION you are looking for then still you will have to hardcode the columns to be joined on.

Comment: Lets say, I am selecting only the columns that are present in all tables. If they are not present, I am displaying a NULL.

Comment: How can do union all to all tables?? Are they having the same datatype and same no of columns??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Query may help you..

```
    SELECT 'CREATE VIEW VIEW_NAME AS'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'SELECT * FROM ['+NAME+']
    UNION ALL' FROM SYS.TABLES where name like 'Warehouse_Inventory%'
```

Comment: This is something he can look at but this will give an error in running the all returned selected statements as the column list is not the same for all tables.

Comment: This query prints UNION ALL for the last line.

Comment: If it is one time activity Remove that UNION ALL manually or it will have merge to single line using XML or @Variable to remove last UNION ALL.... Which one is simple in this case  ........  :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you want to use sys.sysojects instead of other sys views.  Also now sure why when you want to union all tables you would want to search by a table name.....  I would probably recommend a cursor on tables and temp tables to hold your results if you have 200 tables just do to size of the query but if you really really want to do it via union all here is a way...

Build a list of the 10 columns you want.  Then run the query.  you may need to tweak and add some cast/convert function to ensure everything is the right datatypes this can be done dynamically with sys.types and sys.columns or just make sure everything is a NVARCHAR(???) by altering my dynamic sql below and move forward.

```
DECLARE @ListOfColumns AS TABLE (ColumnName VARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO @ListOfColumns (ColumnName) VALUES ('col1'),('col2'),('col3')

DECLARE @SQLStatement NVARCHAR(MAX)

;WITH cteColumnsTableCross AS (
    SELECT
       SchemaName = s.name
       ,t.schema_id
       ,TableName = t.name
       ,l.ColumnName
    FROm
       @ListOfColumns l
       CROSS JOIN sys.tables t
       INNER JOIN sys.schemas s
       ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id
)


, cteColumns AS (
    SELECT
       x.SchemaName
       ,x.TableName
       ,x.ColumnName
       ,ColumnExists = IIF(c.name IS NOT NULL,1,0)
       ,RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY 1 ORDER BY x.TableName DESC)
       --you can add data type by getting from sys.columns and sys.types if desired
    FROM
       cteColumnsTableCross x
       LEFT JOIN sys.tables t
       ON x.TableName = t.name
       AND x.schema_id = t.schema_id
       LEFT JOIN sys.columns c
       ON t.object_id = c.object_id
       AND x.ColumnName = c.name
)

, cteSelectStatements AS (
    SELECT
       TableName = t.name
        ,TableSelect = 'SELECT TableName = ''' + t.name +  ''', ' + 

            STUFF(
            (SELECT ', ' + c.ColumnName + ' = ' + IIF(c.ColumnExists = 0,'NULL',c.ColumnName)
            FROM
                cteColumns c
            WHERE t.name = c.Tablename
            FOR XML PATH(''))
            ,1,1,'')

          + ' FROM ' + t.name + 

          IIF((ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY 1 ORDER BY t.name DESC)) > 1,' UNION ALL ','')
    FROM
       sys.tables t
)

SELECT @SQLStatement = STUFF(
        (SELECT ' ' + TableSelect
        FROM
            cteSelectStatements
       ORDER BY
          TableName
        FOR XML PATH(''))

        ,1,1,'')

PRINT @SQLStatement
--EXECUTE @SQLStatement
```